# I can't make jar file that is using RXTX

Tags: jar, rxtx

I made the following source code and succeed in communicating via RS232.
Then, I attempted to make jar file the source code.I can make the runnable jar file. But it couldn't execute the program when I execute double click　in another PC(In case that I used my PC, The jar file executes properly.).

What should I do to resolve the problem.
I read some involved question, but I do't know what I should do.
So, please let me know the detail procedure how to make jar file.

[I have made jar file of other program before but then it didn't include external jar file. In this time, I used a jar file(RxTxcomm.jar) and two dll file to make the program . so I don't know the way of linking one another.]

My source code
[MyRxTx.java]

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class MyRxTx implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort    serialPort;
Main sample_serial;

public byte[] SendBuffer;
/**
 * The port we're normally going to use.
 */
private final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
        "COM29",
        "COM30",
        "COM31",
};

private InputStream inputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
private static final int Baud_Rate = 115200;

public void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId
                = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Port Name: " + portId.getName() + "\n"
                + "Current Owner: " + portId.getCurrentOwner() + "\n"
                + "Port Type: " + portId.getPortType());
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(
                Baud_Rate,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        serialPort.addEventListener(this);

        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    SendBuffer=new byte[]{(byte)0x41,(byte)0x54};
    write(SendBuffer);
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent Serial_event){

    int received_data = 0;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if(Serial_event.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){

        while(true){
            try{
                received_data = inputStream.read();

                if(received_data == -1) break;

                if((char)received_data != '\r'){
                    buffer.append((char)received_data);
                }

                else{

                    buffer.append('\n');
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex){}
        }//while()文ここまで。

        System.out.println("Receive Data:"+buffer);
        Platform.runLater( () ->{
            sample_serial.label_receive.setText("Receive Data:"+buffer);
        });
    }
}

protected void write(byte[] buffer) throws InterruptedException{
    try {

        outputStream.write(buffer);
        outputStream.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot write:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port. This will prevent
 * port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
        }
    }
}
```

[Main.java]

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageBuilder;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Main extends Application {

MyRxTx myRxTx;
private TextField text_Send;
public  static Label label_receive;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {


    Button btn_send = ButtonBuilder.create().text("Send")
            .prefWidth(100).alignment(Pos.CENTER)
            .id("Send").build();


    text_Send = TextFieldBuilder.create().text("Sending message").alignment(Pos.CENTER)
            .prefWidth(150).build();


    Font Font_receive = Font.font("Arial", FontPosture.REGULAR,20); 
    label_receive = LabelBuilder.create().text("Recieved message")
            .alignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER).prefWidth(400).font(Font_receive).build();


    HBox root1 = HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(100).children(text_Send,btn_send).build();
    HBox root2 = HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(100).children(label_receive).build();
    VBox root3 = VBoxBuilder.create().spacing(15).children(root1,root2).build();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root3);

    myRxTx = new MyRxTx();
    myRxTx.initialize();


    scene.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,actionHandler);


    primaryStage = StageBuilder.create().width(410).height(340).scene(scene).title("Serial Communication Test Tool").build();
    primaryStage.show();

}


EventHandler<ActionEvent> actionHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    public void handle (ActionEvent e){
        Button src =(Button)e.getTarget();
        String text = src.getId();

        System.out.println("Select Button:"+text);

        String text_send = text_Send.getText();

        if(text.equals("Send")){
            try {
                myRxTx.write(text_send.getBytes());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
};

/* main*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Seems to me that the hardcoded PORT_NAMES[] array could cause some problems when trying to retrieve a CommPortIdentifier in your initialize() method. On different PCs, these port names will probably not match, leaving your portId null.